# docker-compose environment variables used as path for volumes don't get resolved

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Docker version (latest for Mac)

```
Version 17.03.1-ce-mac5 (16048)
```

I'm trying to externalise the paths so each developer can change a single file to map components to the right path in their local environment. For example where nginx servers a static website.

```
#localhost.env
INDEX_PATH=/Users/felipe/website/public
```

This is my compose.yml

```
 nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
    - "8081:8081"
    volumes:
     - ${INDEX_PATH}:/etc/nginx/html:ro
    env_file:
      - ./localhost.env
```

In short, I define the *INDEX_PATH* variable to point to my local path and I want nginx to serve the website from there. Another developer should then set

```
#localhost.env
INDEX_PATH=/Users/somebodyElse/whatever/public
```

## The problem

For some reason that I don't understand the local variable somehow does not get resolved properly, at least when using it **as volume's path** .

## Testing

docker-compose config

```
nginx:
    environment:
      INDEX_PATH: /Users/felipe/website/public
    image: nginx
    ports:
    - 8081:8081
    volumes:
    - .:/etc/nginx/html:ro   //HERE I WAS EXPECTING THE PATH
```

As you can see, it just get resolved as **.** (a dot instead of the path /Users/felipe/website/public)

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I believe this feature is supported but can't work out how to do it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `env_file` definition passes environment variables from the file into the container, but it doesn't get picked up in the docker-compose parsing of the yml file. What you can use is a [`.env` file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file) which is loaded before the docker-compose.yml file is parsed, you can even use this to override the docker-compose.yml filename itself.

Comment: spot on mate. Thank you very much!